# Google App Engine - list version instances and get information about them

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memory

I'm using Java SDK for Google App engine and I'm searching for a way to get information about the instances started withing the current version of an app. Specifically, I need to get a list of the existing (started) instances and get their environment (Runtime) so  I can list memory information about each of them.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to scrape this information manually from the backend ui, I believe you're looking for [ModulesService](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/modules/ModulesService) and friends.

Edit: Thinking about it: I guess it would be easier to tap into an instance lifecycle (warumup request, [shutdown hook](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/LifecycleManager)) and simply store the required information.

Comment: I think shutdown hook may help, but i am not sure i can use it on frontend automatic type instances. I will give it a try